# Problem with a sdcard under Android 7.1.2 three partitions can not be mounted / used

Tags: security, internal-storage, external-sd, mount

Happy New Year!

there is a problem with my sdcard under Android 7.1.2 (Custom Rom) (root=true, adb=possible).
The vFat Partition can be used, but the rest is not mounted and can not be used.

mmcblk1p1 vfat 183 GB Status : OK

mmcblk1p2 ext4 16 MB android meta Status: not mounted

mmcblk1p3 ext4 64 GB Status: not mounted (primary) (want to use that partition as adoptable Partition for extra internal memory)

mmcblk1p4 ext4 2 GB Status: not mounted (primary) (want to use that partition as SWAP Partition for extra RAM)

Trying to mount the Partition3 (64 GB) gives the error

> mount: mounting /dev/block/mmcblk1p3 on /data/sdwyt2 failed: Invalid argument

Other similar error messages may also occur.
Any help welcome !

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118449/discussion-on-question-by-shelly-problem-with-a-sdcard-under-android-7-1-2-three).

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer to my question myself here:

Solution: On devices running Android 7.0-8.1, file-based encryption (FBE) can't be used together with adoptable storage.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60173545/why-i-got-this-error-please-adoptable-storage-not-available-on-device-with-nat