# Cant adopt sd card to internal on Huawei Y6 2018

Tags: root-access, rom-flashing, sd-card, storage, huawei

Hi i have a huawei Y6 2018 and i cant adopt my sd card into internal. My phone is rooted and i used the app Root Essentials. It asked me to flash a Plugin (ASPlugin). I Tried to do that but i got the Error 1 i searched for soloutions and found out that you need to take the boot.img and flash it. When i took the magisk.zip and opend it there was no Boot.img. So i downloaded a Boot.img file from the internet and flashed that one. That worked so i tried to now flash the Plugin (ASPlugin) and there was the Error 1 again. I dont know what to do now. I would love to get some help, because my fone only has 16gb internal storage and it is annoying me. I am using a Sandisk 32GB with 98 mb/s.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Problem with a sdcard under Android 7.1.2 three partitions can not be mounted / used](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/232755/problem-with-a-sdcard-under-android-7-1-2-three-partitions-can-not-be-mounted)